# ObjectUtils.equal(x,y) null can work

Tags: java

If `x == null` does `ObjectUtils.equal(x, y)` work?

Comment: Why don't you try it and let us know?

Comment: I suppose it depends what the definition of ObjectUtils is.

Comment: sry for putting the down vote i wanted my badge :) seemed like the right post to put a down vote on.

Comment: hey, at least he can get a badge for deleting a -3 question lol.

Comment: @harto And `y` for that matter.

Comment: @harto *And* the definition of "work".

Answer (score 2):

See the [JavaDoc of the method](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/ObjectUtils.html#equals%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29). It says null works.

Comment: Unless it is another `ObjectUtils`.

Answer (score 1):

### **    Yes!    **

Comment: or, "No".
Depends on the outcome of your test?

Comment: Ah, jeez Mitch, here I was impressed by your confidence, and you go and qualify it...

Comment: I was testing your confidence in your first impression.  You were easily dissuaded. (is there a badge for that?)